# Macbook Pro - Early 2013 - Rebooting

Tags: macbook-pro, crash

my MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Early 2013) keeps crashing and rebooting. I can't seem to figure out the issue. hoping someone can help -

Here's the problem report that it's showing me now that it's restarted

panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff7f8e8ac57f): GPU Panic: mux-regs 3 0 a0 d9 9 8 severity 3 WS-ready 1 switch-state 0 IG FBs 0 EG FBs 1:f power-state 0 3D busy HDA idle system-state 1 power-level 20:20 power-retry 0 connect-change 0 : NVRM[0/1:0:0]: Read Error 0x00000100: CFG 0xffffffff 0xffffffff 0xffffffff, BAR0 0xc0000000 0xffffff9130d34000 0x0e7150a2, D0, P1/4

Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff8110733270 : 0xffffff800c339a3b 
0xffffff81107332c0 : 0xffffff800c470fe5 
0xffffff8110733300 : 0xffffff800c462a5e 
0xffffff8110733350 : 0xffffff800c2e0a40 
0xffffff8110733370 : 0xffffff800c339127 
0xffffff8110733470 : 0xffffff800c33950b 
0xffffff81107334c0 : 0xffffff800cad17f9 
0xffffff8110733530 : 0xffffff7f8e8ac57f 
0xffffff8110733590 : 0xffffff7f8f6592f1 
0xffffff8110733610 : 0xffffff7f8f72611b 
0xffffff8110733670 : 0xffffff7f8f7261c8 
0xffffff81107336a0 : 0xffffff7f8f9bc91e 
0xffffff81107336f0 : 0xffffff7f8f9bc016 
0xffffff8110733760 : 0xffffff7f8f750130 
0xffffff8110733780 : 0xffffff7f8f65f988 
0xffffff8110733830 : 0xffffff7f8f65caa1 
0xffffff81107339b0 : 0xffffff7f8f65e619 
0xffffff8110733ab0 : 0xffffff7f8f5f1395 
0xffffff8110733ca0 : 0xffffff7f8f5efac1 
0xffffff8110733cc0 : 0xffffff7f8fb4c556 
0xffffff8110733da0 : 0xffffff7f8fb4c004 
0xffffff8110733e00 : 0xffffff7f8fb4c418 
0xffffff8110733e20 : 0xffffff800ca44f79 
0xffffff8110733e90 : 0xffffff800ca44e99 
0xffffff8110733ec0 : 0xffffff800c37b625 
0xffffff8110733f40 : 0xffffff800c37b151 
0xffffff8110733fa0 : 0xffffff800c2e013e 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl(4.5.9)[3417B519-7556-3656-B708-39FE282F46F2]@0xffffff7f8e89d000->0xffffff7f8e8b0fff
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl(4.5.9)[486C69C3-8BFB-3D78-AB64-242EA92618D9]@0xffffff7f8e83f000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily(1.4)[4A40B298-87E0-373E-84A9-9A2227924F8F]@0xffffff7f8ccc8000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[AA7C7A4F-9F5D-3533-9E78-177C3B6A72BF]@0xffffff7f8ccda000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(568)[247C211E-C250-351C-BCE2-4DB9D3003E10]@0xffffff7f8e842000
            dependency: com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl(4.5.9)[AB076CA9-0E87-382E-BDF3-527D9F278B23]@0xffffff7f8e893000
         com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAResman(14.0)[ECB33CB3-2FE3-3E99-A4E6-ED7C5DA6D543]@0xffffff7f8f5ec000->0xffffff7f8f8c3fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[AA7C7A4F-9F5D-3533-9E78-177C3B6A72BF]@0xffffff7f8ccda000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport(568)[A5DE893D-E9E0-3946-B67F-A287A52B3001]@0xffffff7f8f27d000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(568)[247C211E-C250-351C-BCE2-4DB9D3003E10]@0xffffff7f8e842000
            dependency: com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl(4.5.9)[AB076CA9-0E87-382E-BDF3-527D9F278B23]@0xffffff7f8e893000
         com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAGK100Hal(14.0)[D9BD5415-852D-3F99-B5D9-9E4FD7CABEEC]@0xffffff7f8f8c4000->0xffffff7f8fa6ffff
            dependency: com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAResman(14.0.0)[ECB33CB3-2FE3-3E99-A4E6-ED7C5DA6D543]@0xffffff7f8f5ec000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[AA7C7A4F-9F5D-3533-9E78-177C3B6A72BF]@0xffffff7f8ccda000
         com.apple.driver.AGPM(111.2.5)[E2C8E019-70B9-3582-ABA0-3C3A6D531D20]@0xffffff7f8fb46000->0xffffff7f8fb66fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[AA7C7A4F-9F5D-3533-9E78-177C3B6A72BF]@0xffffff7f8ccda000
            dependency: com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily(6.0.0d8)[A48CD297-C18E-34DB-B172-A74CECBF1F19]@0xffffff7f8f1a3000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport(568)[A5DE893D-E9E0-3946-B67F-A287A52B3001]@0xffffff7f8f27d000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(568)[247C211E-C250-351C-BCE2-4DB9D3003E10]@0xffffff7f8e842000
            dependency: com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl(4.5.9)[AB076CA9-0E87-382E-BDF3-527D9F278B23]@0xffffff7f8e893000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task

Mac OS version:
19B88

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 19.0.0: Thu Oct 17 16:17:15 PDT 2019; root:xnu-6153.41.3~29/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 7503CD47-851F-321E-8747-50DB4299165F
Kernel slide:     0x000000000c000000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff800c200000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff800c100000
System model name: MacBookPro10,1 (Mac-C3EC7CD22292981F)
System shutdown begun: NO
Panic diags file available: YES (0x0)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 7005299357900
last loaded kext at 5752423119914: >!AXsanScheme    3 (addr 0xffffff7f8f1b6000, size 32768)
last unloaded kext at 5965563509928: >!AXsanScheme  3 (addr 0xffffff7f8f1b6000, size 32768)
loaded kexts:

> AudioAUUC  1.70
>   @AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics   4.5.9
>   @fileutil   20.036.15
>   |IOUserEthernet 1.0.1
>   |IO!BSerialManager  7.0.1f1
>   pmtelemetry    1
>   AGPM   111.2.5
>   X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
>   !APlatformEnabler  2.7.0d0
>   !AMikeyHIDDriver   131
>   !AUpstreamUserClient   3.6.8
>   !AHV   1
>   AGDCBacklightControl   4.5.9
>   !AMikeyDriver  283.14
>   @GeForce    14.0.0
>   !A!IHD4000Graphics 14.0.2
>   @Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X    7.0.0
>   !AHDA  283.14
>   eficheck   1
>   !ASMCPDRC  1.0.0
>   !AMCCSControl  1.13
>   !ASMCLMU   212
>   !ALPC  3.1
>   AirPort.Brcm4360   1400.1.1
>   !A!IFramebufferCapri   14.0.2
>   !AMuxControl   4.5.9
>   !A!ISlowAdaptiveClocking   4.0.0
>   !AThunderboltIP    3.1.3
>   @filesystems.autofs 3.0
>   !UTCKeyboard   255
>   !UTCButtons    255
>   @BootCache  40
>   @!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeDataless    1.0.0d1
>   !AVirtIO   1.0
>   @!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeZlib    1.0.0
>   @filesystems.hfs.kext   522.0.9
>   @filesystems.apfs   1412.41.1
>   !ASDXC 1.7.7
>   @private.KextAudit  1.0
>   !AAHCIPort 341.0.2
>   !ASmartBatteryManager  161.0.0
>   !AACPIButtons  6.1
>   !ARTC  2.0
>   !AHPET 1.8
>   !ASMBIOS   2.1
>   !AACPIEC   6.1
>   !AAPIC 1.7
>   !A!ICPUPowerManagementClient   222.0.0
>   $TMSafetyNet    8
>   @!ASystemPolicy 2.0.0
>   @nke.applicationfirewall    303
>   $!AImage4   1
>   !A!ICPUPowerManagement 222.0.0
>   |EndpointSecurity   1
>   |IOAVB!F    800.17
>   !ASSE  1.0
>   @nvidia.driver.NVDAGK100Hal 14.0.0
>   @nvidia.driver.NVDAResman   14.0.0
>   DspFuncLib 283.14
>   @kext.OSvKernDSPLib 529
>   @plugin.IOgPTPPlugin    810.1
>   !ABacklightExpert  1.1.0
>   |IONDRVSupport  568
>   @!AGPUWrangler  4.5.9
>   !AHDA!C    283.14
>   |IOHDA!F    283.14
>   |IOAudio!F  300.2
>   @vecLib.kext    1.2.0
>   X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
>   !ASMBus!C  1.0.18d1
>   |IOEthernetAVB!C    1.1.0
>   !ASMBusPCI 1.0.14d1
>   IOPlatformPlugin!F 6.0.0d8
>   |IO80211!F  1200.12.2b1
>   |IOSkywalk!F    1
>   mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
>   corecapture    1.0.4
>   |IOAccelerator!F2   438.2.7
>   @!AGraphicsDeviceControl    4.5.9
>   |IOGraphics!F   568
>   !AGraphicsControl  4.5.9
>   |IOSlowAdaptiveClocking!F   1.0.0
>   @kext.triggers  1.0
>   |Broadcom!BHost!CUSBTransport   7.0.1f1
>   |IO!BHost!CUSBTransport 7.0.1f1
>   |IO!BHost!CTransport    7.0.1f1
>   |IO!B!F 7.0.1f1
>   |IO!BPacketLogger   7.0.1f1
>   !UMultitouch   264
>   usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.2
>   usb.networking 5.0.0
>   usb.!UHostCompositeDevice  1.2
>   usb.!UHub  1.2
>   |IOSurface  269.6
>   |IOSerial!F 11
>   @filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext 1
>   !AThunderboltDPInAdapter   6.2.3
>   !AThunderboltDPAdapter!F   6.2.3
>   !AThunderboltPCIDownAdapter    2.5.2
>   !AThunderboltNHI   5.8.0
>   |IOThunderbolt!F    7.4.6
>   |IOAHCIBlock!S  316.40.3
>   |IOAHCI!F   290.0.1
>   usb.!UEHCIPCI  1.2
>   usb.!UEHCI 1.2
>   usb.!UXHCIPCI  1.2
>   usb.!UXHCI 1.2
>   |IOUSB!F    900.4.2
>   !AEFINVRAM 2.1
>   !AEFIRuntime   2.1
>   |IOSMBus!F  1.1
>   |IOHID!F    2.0.0
>   $quarantine 4
>   $sandbox    300.0
>   @kext.!AMatch   1.0.0d1
>   |IOTimeSync!F   810.1
>   |IONetworking!F 3.4
>   !AFDEKeyStore  28.30
>   !AEffaceable!S 1.0
>   !AKeyStore 2
>   !UTDM  489.41.1
>   |IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice  422.0.2
>   |IOUSBMass!SDriver  157.40.7
>   |IOSCSIArchitectureModel!F  422.0.2
>   DiskImages 493.0.0
>   |IO!S!F 2.1
>   |CoreAnalytics!F    1
>   !AMobileFileIntegrity  1.0.5
>   @kext.CoreTrust 1
>   !ACredentialManager    1.0
>   KernelRelayHost    1
>   |IOUSBHost!F    1.2
>   !UHostMergeProperties  1.2
>   usb.!UCommon   1.0
>   !ABusPower!C   1.0
>   !ASEPManager   1.0.1
>   IOSlaveProcessor   1
>   |IOReport!F 47
>   !AACPIPlatform 6.1
>   !ASMC  3.1.9
>   watchdog   1
>   |IOPCI!F    2.9
>   |IOACPI!F   1.4
>   @kec.Libm   1
>   @kec.pthread    1
>   @kec.corecrypto 1.0

Comment: What is the macOS you have on it? Have you tried to reset SMC and NVRAM ? Looking generally, it seems to be a kernel panic.

Comment: I’m on Catalina